# How to fit in an image inside span tag when onclick?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image inside a span tag. But the problem is the image doesn't fit inside the span tag. Instead a part of the image goes out of the span tag.

I want to have when onclick on the word span it change the image color while when i onclick on that image it will change the color of the text. I guess something wrong on my code.

How can I achieve it?

MY HTML :

```
<div class="games-platform-item pt-item">
<ul class="games-sub-menu clearfix">
<li class="tab1 current">
    <!-- <img src="../images/abc11.jpg"/ class="topimgG1" "> -->
    <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg1">
    <label class="topimgG1" for="rdoImg1"></label>
    <span>编辑精选</span>
</li>
<li class="tab2">
    <div>
        <!-- <img src="../images/abc2.jpg"/ class="topimgG2" "> -->
        <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg2">
        <label class="topimgG2" for="rdoImg2"></label>
        <span>老虎机</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="tab3">
    <!-- <img src="../images/abc3.jpg"/ class="topimgG3" "> -->
    <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg3">
    <label class="topimgG3" for="rdoImg3"></label>
    <span>桌面游戏</span>
</li>
<li class="tab4">
    <!-- <img src="../images/abc4.jpg"/ class="topimgG4" "> -->
    <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg4">
    <label class="topimgG4" for="rdoImg4"></label>
    <span>累计大奖</span>
</li>
<li class="tab5">
    <!-- <img src="../images/abc5.jpg"/ class="topimgG5" "> -->
    <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg5">
    <label class="topimgG5" for="rdoImg5"></label>
    <span>小游戏</span>
</li>
<li class="tab6">
    <!-- <img src="../images/abc6.jpg"/ class="topimgG6" ">   -->
    <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg6">
    <label class="topimgG6" for="rdoImg6"></label>
    <span>视频扑克</span>
</li>
<li class="tab7">
    <!-- <img src="../images/abc7.jpg"/ class="topimgG7" "> -->
    <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg7">
    <label class="topimgG7" for="rdoImg7"></label>
    <span>所有游戏</span>
</li>
```

MY CSS :

```
/*Hide the Radio Button*/

.games-sub-menu input[type=radio] {
    display: none
}
/*Set a box for the label, this is what is clicked on*/

.games-sub-menu label {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
}
/*Set Images...this would work better with sprites*/

.games-sub-menu label.topimgG1 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 820px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG1 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc1_onclick.jpg");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG2 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 690px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG2 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc2_onclick.jpg");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG3 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 560px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    clear: both;
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG3 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc3_onclick.jpg");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG4 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc4.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 430px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG4 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc4_onclick.jpg");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG5 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc5.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 305px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG5 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc5_onclick.jpg");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG6 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc6.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 18 5px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG6 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc6_onclick.jpg");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG7 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc7.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 43px;
    top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG7 {
    background-image: url("../images/abc7_onclick.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Try like this in css   img { display : inline }

Comment: @SudharsanS Hi , sorry im still new in css .. where should i put this display :inline ?

Comment: It is possible to change the color of the `<span>` element when `<input>` is checked. Not certain if it is possible to change color of `<span>` when `<label>` is checked without checking another `<input>`. You could try to create two sets of `<input>`, `<label>` pairs, and substitute `<label>` for `<span>` element. Or use `<input type="checkbox">` elements, which toggle `checked` stated when clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to have when onclick on the word span it change the image color
>   while when i onclick on that image it will change the color of the
>   text.

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `<input type="checkbox">` with two `<label>` elements as adjacent siblings, both with `for` attribute referencing previous `<input type="checkbox">` element

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
}
:checked + label + label {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
:checked + label {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<label for="1"></label>
<label for="1">text</label>
```